# Flash video (swf) not showing up

Tags: html, flash

Is there anything wrong with the below code? Video is not showing up

```
<div style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;width:100%;height:100%">
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" height="592" id="player" width="500">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.diareception.com/flvPlayer/Titanium1010.swf?key=key" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="userKey=key&amp;videoIndex=4" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<embed allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" flashvars="userKey=key&amp;videoIndex=4" height="592" name="player"   
src="http://www.diareception.com/flvPlayer/Titanium1010.swf?key=key" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="500">
</embed></object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is something wrong with your SWF file url/path. I tried replacing your swf file path with a sample SWF file and it worked perfectly fine.

Suggest your to recheck the SWF filepath.

Comment: Hi Peeje. Thanks. I got that path from my client. I'll check with him.